# Communicate to a web application via application that is running on a PC that is connected to internet via Wifi

Tags: networking

This is my application setup.

I have written an application (in Qt ) which will run on a linux computer (Ubuntu). The application accepts requests from web app and sends them to a serial device that is connected to the computer. Also application will send back the response to web app as well. This linux computer is connected to internet via wifi router.

Now my question is, Is there a way (other than port forwarding in wifi router) that I can achieve this functionality. Using port forwarding I can ask the router to forward the requests  coming for a particular port to my computer at a particular port and my application would be listening for that. But for that I would have to configure the router and I don't want to do that. Is there a way I can do that automatically?

Thanks,
DPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is traversing non-routable NAT addresses.

UPNP is an option: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play

It will automatically configure port forwarding.

There is a library out there called STUNT for this as well:

http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu/stunt.php